# IValueConverter ConvertBack in Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps, windows-10

I am having a strange issue with my `IValueConverter` that only happens when the device my app is running on is running Windows 10. It works just fine on Windows 8.1.

Basically I have a button whose background is an image of a stoplight. When the user presses the button the stoplight changes colors to the next color of the stoplight "Red/yellow/green/off." This triggers the binding to use my `IValueConverter` to convert that new image to a string value that is then stored in the `TaskStatus` property of the `DataContext`. It does this using the following `ConvertBack` method:

```
 public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            BitmapImage sentImage = (BitmapImage) value;
            if (sentImage.UriSource.ToString()
                .Equals(@"ms-appx:/Assets/Icon/GrayLightTransBack.png", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return "";
            }
            else if(sentImage.UriSource.ToString()
                .Equals(@"ms-appx:/Assets/Icon/GreenLightTransBack.png", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return "X";
            }
            else if (sentImage.UriSource.ToString()
                .Equals(@"ms-appx:/Assets/Icon/RedLightTransBack.png", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return "/";
            }
            else if (sentImage.UriSource.ToString()
                .Equals(@"ms-appx:/Assets/Icon/YellowLightTransBack.png", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return "O";
            }
            return null;
        }
```

As I said, this works great on Windows 8.1. The user presses the stoplight button and the following method is executed:

```
private void StoplightButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button stopLightButton = (Button)sender;
    ImageBrush sentImage = (ImageBrush)stopLightButton.Background;
    BitmapImage buttonImage = (BitmapImage)sentImage.ImageSource;

    if (buttonImage.UriSource.ToString()
        .Equals(@"ms-appx:/Assets/Icon/GrayLightTransBack.png", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        ((ImageBrush)stopLightButton.Background).ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:/Assets/Icon/RedLightTransBack.png"));
    }
    else if (buttonImage.UriSource.ToString()
        .Equals(@"ms-appx:/Assets/Icon/RedLightTransBack.png", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        ((ImageBrush)stopLightButton.Background).ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:/Assets/Icon/YellowLightTransBack.png"));
    }
    else if (buttonImage.UriSource.ToString()
        .Equals(@"ms-appx:/Assets/Icon/YellowLightTransBack.png", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        ((ImageBrush)stopLightButton.Background).ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:/Assets/Icon/GreenLightTransBack.png"));
    }
    else if (buttonImage.UriSource.ToString()
        .Equals(@"ms-appx:/Assets/Icon/GreenLightTransBack.png", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        ((ImageBrush)stopLightButton.Background).ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:/Assets/Icon/GrayLightTransBack.png"));
    }
}
```

So after the `Button`s `ImageSource` is changed, it triggers the `ConvertBack` to convert that image to a string value that I can then store.

The problem is that when the app is running on Windows 10. The value that is sent to `ConvertBack` is the ***current*** image that the stoplight is using, not the new one that it was just changed to.

So if I change a stoplight from Red to Green, the following block is executed:

```
else if (buttonImage.UriSource.ToString()
    .Equals(@"ms-appx:/Assets/Icon/RedLightTransBack.png", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    ((ImageBrush)stopLightButton.Background).ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:/Assets/Icon/YellowLightTransBack.png"));
}
```

On Windows 8.1, `ConvertBack` would then be called and the `object value` would be an image with the path of the yellow stoplight `YellowLightTransBack.png`.

On Windows 10, `ConvertBack` is still called, but the value that is passed is the image of the red stoplight, not the yellow stoplight that the button was just changed to.

What would cause this behavior? I am pulling my hair out trying to figure this out and I can't think of any reason why the wrong value would be sent to an `IValueConverter` based solely on the OS.

Comment: Well that is so long to go through try making a smaller example out of it

Comment: I can reproduce your issues in my side on Windows 10 Build 10240. This is strange and I will test it on the latest version to see if the problem still there. Besides, there is a workaround can implement your requirement, but I'm not sure whether you need it.